# Custom Android Keyboard 'Go' doesn't submit URL or anything?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard

I have a return key on my custom keyboard with android:code="10". The keyboard updates the keyIcon based on the EditorInfo.

The issue I'm having is that when the button is 'Go', meaning EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO is on, pressing Go doesn't submit.

The return button works, but when I type a URL in a search box and press Go, nothing happens. It just does a space/return.

How do I solve this?

I could check if they are pressing the Return key and that EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO is true and then "submit", but I don't how to do that. I'm pretty sure the 'Go' function is implemented by the URL text box, not something I should be doing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSEcv.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text editor you are typing in is the current Input Editor.

You can perform an action on that input connection using currentInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) or whatever other action you want.

For it to automatically do the input action you need, use the following:

```
val imeOptions = currentInputEditorInfo.imeOptions
val action = imeOptions and EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION
currentInputConnection.performEditorAction(action)
```

Other helpful links, such as for changing the icon on the keyboard:

[Cannot change Enter Key label for Custom keyboard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920030/cannot-change-enter-key-label-for-custom-keyboard-in-android)

[How to perform a search action by android custom keyboard action button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069778/how-to-perform-a-search-action-by-android-custom-keyboard-action-button)